# Negative polarity item 'any' & Positive polarity item 'some'

Tags: polarity-items, some-vs-any

In the book that I'm now reading, it says that the sentence

(1) "Only two of us had some experience in sailing"

is **ungrammatical**, because **'only'** has negative meaning, so the positive polarity item **'some'** cannot be positioned in this sentence.

Therefore,

(2) "Only two of us had any experience in sailing"

is the correct sentence according to this book.

However, I am now really confused by these two sentences. Do they have the same meaning, and also, is it right to say the sentence (1) is strictly ungrammatical?

Comment: Why won't you tell what is the book is called, and who wrote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [1] **Only two of us had some experience in sailing.*
>
> [2] *Only two of us had any experience in sailing.*

Yes, (1) is ungrammatical.

"Any" and "some" are polar-sensitive items, with "some" having a positive orientation, and "any" a negative orientation.

"Only" is not negative, but it is semantically close to a negative, in that *Only two of us* entails that *No one other than the two of us*.

Comment: Odd, [1] sounds fine to me, it seems to suggest more experience than "any."